# Updating value of a document MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Inside a database called **user_notifications** there is a collection for each user with their user id.

There should a static document that would contain a **counter** column default set to 0 for each collection.

In a simple method call i need to increment the counter value by 1, as a newbie in MongoDB i think i am messed up. Need some idea, here is my object that would do that:

```
private function increment_notification()
{

    // database   => notification
    // collection => _238
    // document   => unseen_counter

    $unseen = $this->notification->_238->unseen_counter; // selecting a single document

    // if the document didn't exists then create the document and 
    // set a default value 0 to the counter row.

    if(!$unseen) {
        // create a new document
        $this->notification->insertOne([
            '_id' => 'unseen_counter',
            'counter' => '0'
        ]);
    } else {
        // we already have the document
        // now update the counter value by 1
        $unseen->update([
            '$set' => [
                'counter' => $unseen['counter'] + 1;
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

I ended up writing this method as a pseudo code `:[`

As a beginner in MongoDB, how is my schema design? any suggestion to make it better? 
Also, how i should run the above queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to use the `$inc` operator.  Here is [documentation and example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) for `$inc`.

Comment: Could you provide more detail here?